# How t get Pressure sensitivity work on a Wacom bamboo pen ctl-460?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, wacom, graphics-tablet

My tablet works fine except for the fact that I don't have any pressure sensitivity.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Edit: I have the same problem, but I can add that pressure sensitivity used to work under 11.04.

Answer (score 1):

Which programs are you trying? There are problems in 11.10, gnome completely broke their wacom support and inkscape and gimp both can't use pressure sensitivity any more.

This is a known problem, which we hope will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: It doesn't work in mypaint, too.